# Extended float parsing - automatically parse pi

Tags: python, parsing, pi

In python, one can turn string into float by just calling the float constructor with that string:

```
>>> float('3.14')
3.14
```

However, I would like to be able to also parse string `'pi'` as `math.pi`, and not only just plain `'pi'` but also `'-pi'` and with everything that float parsing does (i.e. whitespaces before and after the actual number don't matter).

Should I write it myself, I would have to reimplement a lot of the original float parsing logic which I obviously don't want. Is there any already existing function or library that does that?

Comment: You could just call `float(x)` if `x` is not `'pi'` or `'-pi'`, no need to reimplement the float parsing logic.

Comment: @kennytm No because it's not just ``'pi'`` but also ``'  pi'``, ``'pi   '``, ``'  pi  '`` etc. The ``pi`` should be treated in an identical way any other number is treated, including that spaces before and/or after that number can be there and the thing still parses successfully.

Comment: If spaces are problem then call `x = x.strip()` first (or even call `.lower()`), which is still manageable for write-it-yourself.

Comment: Just call `strip()` over the string as first thing before doing the comparisons. It's not like code written by others in libraries is more magical than what you can write yourself - especially for this kind of trivial stuff I wouldn't get so worried about implementing this tiny bit of logic myself.

Answer (score 2):

Write it yourself. You could just check if the input is the string `"pi"` after stripping. If it is not, forward to the original `float` call.

```
import math

def float_or_pi(x):
    x = x.strip().lower()
    if x in ('pi', '+pi'):
        return math.pi
    elif x == '-pi':
        return -math.pi
    else:
        return float(x)


assert float_or_pi('  PI  ') == math.pi
assert float_or_pi(' 3.25 ') == 3.25

# (off-topic note: don't try to `==` floats at home.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda one liner function

`get_value = lambda x : math.pi if x == 'pi' else ( -math.pi if x == '-pi' else float(x))
get_value('pi')
get_value('-pi')
get_value('4.3')`